# how to make a bind a value to be used in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm new to Xaml(first project im working on in it), and would love some help. I'm trying to make a radial gauge to be saved in a .dll to be used in other projects but have hit a wall trying to pass a angle value for the needle.
In the end i want to be able to call for the gauge giving an angle like a method call.

ex:
`<RadialGauge Angle="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="532,278,0,0"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" />`

im having trouble sending a value to be used by my gauge though, any help would be appreciated.

My .xaml

```
<UserControl
x:Class="DTIGauge.RadialGauge"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:DTIGauge"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Height="450" Width="450"

>

<Grid>
    <Ellipse Fill="White" Margin="30"/>

    <Grid >

        <Polygon Height="450" Width="450" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Red" Points="225,37 220,228 225,240 230,228">
            <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform CenterX="225" CenterY="225" Angle="{Binding Path=the_angle}"/>
            </Polygon.RenderTransform>
        </Polygon>
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="0°" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" Foreground="White" Height="450" Width="450" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform  CenterX="225" CenterY="225" Angle="0"/>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="20°" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" Foreground="White" Height="450" Width="450" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform  CenterX="225" CenterY="225" Angle="20"/>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>

    <!--...And a lot more markers-->
</Grid>
```

my .cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The User Control item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234236

namespace DTIGauge
{
    public sealed partial class RadialGauge
    {

        Int32 temp;
        public RadialGauge(Int32 myInt)
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            temp = myInt;

        }
        Int32 _myint;
        public Int32 the_angle
        {
            get { return this._myint; }
            set { this._myint = temp; }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a Dependency Property ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) on your UserControl's code behind.

A dependency property has all the necessary functionality to support data binding in WPF.

You could modify your code behind to include this instead of your Angle property:

```
// Dependency Property
public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty = 
     DependencyProperty.Register( "Angle", typeof(int),
     typeof(RadialGauge), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0));

// .NET Property wrapper
public int Angle
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(AngleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AngleProperty, value); }
}
```

And your XAML would need to be updated to:

```
<RotateTransform CenterX="225" CenterY="225" Angle="{Binding Path=Angle, ElementName=userControl}"/>
```

To bind to this property.

There's a handy code snippet in Visual Studio that helps create this code. Just type "propdp" and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice.

To learn more about dependency properties and how binding works in WPF, check out this website: http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html

PS: I would recommend a Double value for Angle, instead of Int.

Good luck :)

Comment: Excellent answer! A DP is definitely the way to go here.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET thanks for tidying up my text - the iPad keyboard was overly helpful :)

Comment: Not a problem. Your post was pretty good for being from a tablet :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the datacontext of your usercontrol with the object that you want to bind in your xaml. To help you understand better How it works, I proporse you this design, applying MVVM pattern:

Declare a class as I show below:

```
public class RadialGougeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _angle;

    public int Angle
    {
        get
        {
            return _angle;
        }
        set
        {
            _angle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Angle");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Next, in your user control,set the datacontext of your root grid at this way:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Gouge"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <YourNamespace:RadialGougeViewModel  x:Key="RadialGougeViewModel "/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource RadialGougeViewModel}">
</Grid>
```

Now you can use the viemodel properties in the controls declared inside the Grid:

```
 <Polygon Height="450" Width="450" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Red" Points="225,37 220,228 225,240 230,228">
        <Polygon.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="225" CenterY="225" Angle="{Binding Path=Angle}"/>
        </Polygon.RenderTransform>
</Polygon>
```

If you want understand in details how work this pattern I recommend you read this article:[WPF MVVM step by step (Basics to Advance Level)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level)